# Javascript closest selector but for sibling

Tags: javascript

I have this html:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="qsearch">Qsearch</label>
  <input id="search1" type="search" value="" name="s">
  
  <br>
  <label for="num">Num</label>
  <input type="number" value="" name="Num">
  <br>
  <label for="a">A</label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="a">
  <br>
  <label for="a">B</label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="b">
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
console.log( document.getElementById("search1").closest("input[type='text']") );
</script>
```

I want to get the next text input closest to search input without knowing the ID. But i can't seems to use closest()

What is the correct way to do it using vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

closest looks up in the DOM. In your case `input#search1` is fist element in the DOM. You may try a recursive function like this and check if the element have next sibling. If it has next sibling and matches the type then return it else call the recursive function

```js
function getNextSibling(elem, selector) {
  let sibling = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // check if the element have next sibling
  while (sibling) {
    if (sibling.matches(selector)) {
      return sibling;
    }
    sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling;
  }
};

const x = document.getElementById("search1")
  .nextElementSibling;
console.log(getNextSibling(x, "input[type='text']"))
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="qsearch">Qsearch</label>
  <input id="search1" type="search" value="" name="s">

  <br>
  <label for="num">Num</label>
  <input type="number" value="" name="Num">
  <br>
  <label for="a">A</label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="a">
  <br>
  <label for="a">B</label>
  <input type="text" value="" name="b">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```